# How to check if an insert / update query was successful?

Tags: php

I am converting my php files to prepared statements I got the select statements to work. But with update and Insert i'm not quite sure of how to check if it was a success?

I tried

```php
 if ($statement == "True") {}
```

No avail.

Old Code (Before prepared statements):

```php
    $nsql = "UPDATE `Games` SET `Users`='$str', `Expire`='$str2' WHERE Pincode='$pin'";
    echo $nsql;
    if ($connect->query($nsql) === TRUE) {
        echo 'done';
    }else {
        echo "fail";
    }
```

New code

```php
    $statement = $mysqli->prepare( "UPDATE `Games` SET `Users`=?, `Expire`=? WHERE Pincode=?");
    $statement->bind_param("ssi", $str, $str2 $pin);
    $statement->execute();

    if () { // <--- Not sure what this would be to check if it worked

    }
```

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: `if ($statement->execute())` <- `execute()` returns a bool value

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php - *Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.*

Comment: @treyBake Should I have ```php $statement->execute(); if ($statement->execute()) {}``` or just ```php if ($statement->execute()) {} ```

Comment: as a I posted - run the execute as the condition

Comment: You don't need to check that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am right ->execute() only returns only true or false if the query is excecuted right, if you update or delete a row you need to check if there are rows affected you can use `if ($statement->affected_rows > 0)` if no rows are affected it will return -1

Comment: affected_rows = 0 doesn't mean that query was a failure.